# XSD ignoring namespace during validation xsd with imports

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

this question i base on simple example.
I have 2 XSDs

**main.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:sub="urn:xsd:subXSD"
           xmlns="urn:xsd:mainXSD"
           targetNamespace="urn:xsd:mainXSD"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import namespace="urn:xsd:subXSD" schemaLocation="sub.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="main">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="elementA"/>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="subElement" type="sub:SubType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**sub.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="urn:xsd:subXSD"
           targetNamespace="urn:xsd:subXSD"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="SubType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="subA"/>
            <xs:element name="subB"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Now I try to validate 2 xmls

**withNamespace.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:sub="urn:xsd:subXSD"
      xmlns="urn:xsd:mainXSD"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:xsd:mainXSD main.xsd
                   urn:xsd:subXSD sub.xsd">
    <elementA>
        Element A content
    </elementA>
    <subElement>
        <sub:subA>sub 1 a</sub:subA>
        <sub:subB>sub 1 b</sub:subB>
    </subElement>
    <subElement>
        <sub:subA>sub 2 a</sub:subA>
        <sub:subB>sub 2 b</sub:subB>
    </subElement>
</main>
```

**withoutNamespace.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<main xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="urn:xsd:mainXSD"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:xsd:mainXSD main.xsd">
    <elementA>
        Element A content
    </elementA>
    <subElement>
        <subA>sub 1 a</subA>
        <subB>sub 1 b</subB>
    </subElement>
    <subElement>
        <subA>sub 2 a</subA>
        <subB>sub 2 b</subB>
    </subElement>
</main>
```

To validate xmls I use simple implementation:

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class XSDExample {

    public static final String BASE_DIR = "...";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(BASE_DIR + "main.xsd"));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            System.out.println(validate(validator, "withNamespace.xml"));
            System.out.println(validate(validator, "withoutNamespace.xml"));
        } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String validate(Validator validator, String fileName) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(fileName);
        try {
            validator.reset();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(BASE_DIR + fileName)));
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return "Valid";
    }
}
```

Output of execution this code:

```
withNamespace.xml
Valid
withoutNamespace.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'subA'. One of '{"urn:xsd:subXSD":subA}' is expected.
```

It is possible to create one XSD that will allow me to verify XML files with and without the imported XSD schema namespace?
Or maybe there is javax.xml.validation.Validator configuration to skip namespace checking?

Comment: `<sub:subA>` and `<subA>` are two different elements. Same as two classes named `Foo` in packages `com.example1` and `com.example2` are two different classes. Same as two files named `hello.txt` in folders `a` and `b` are two different files. **They are not the same**, so they shouldn't be treated the same.

Comment: `withoutNamespace.xml` is wrong (misnamed), because all the elements have a namespace. `xmlns="urn:xsd:mainXSD"` means that any element without a `prefix:` belongs to namespace `urn:xsd:mainXSD`, which means that `<subA>` and `<subB>` are in that same namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is possible to create one XSD that will allow me to verify XML
>   files with and without the imported XSD schema namespace?

No, there isn't.

What you can do is transform both inputs (using XSLT) to a common form before schema validation. Doing a normalizing transform as the first step in your validation pipeline is a very valuable technique, and not widely enough known.